# Support OSX vCard extensions on Windows/Thunderbird

Tags: windows, macos, webdav, address-book, vcard

Let me explain.

The built-in address book client in OSX (Contacts.app) allows you to create groups of contacts on a CardDAV server. The way it does this is that it uploads on the server a vCard that references other vCards (by their UUID).

For example such a vCard looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
UID:C724FD05-15F0-0001-8688-A17419801EDA
N:Liste 1;;;;
FN:Liste 1
REV:20160714T110110Z
X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-KIND:group
X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-MEMBER:urn:uuid:5c8f7300-a727-4a5c-92dd-dc093d2fd5f3
X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-MEMBER:urn:uuid:b9e2a473-a0c1-4795-81fa-c3657cc9ad33
X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-MEMBER:urn:uuid:049854fc-03fb-4433-bc50-84da7d4fbff0
END:VCARD
```

When I try to connect a Windows client running Thunderbird to the same CardDAV server (with Sogo Connector), Thunderbird doesn't recognize the `X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-KIND` and `X-ADDRESSBOOKSERVER-MEMBER` extensions and isn't able to group contacts the same way Contacts.app does.

Is there a way to do this?